# Traceback (most recent call last) File "Main.py" how to solve

Tags: python, telegram-bot

i'm trying to create a bot for telegram but now i'm stuck on this error i don't know how to resolve

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99ZXh.png)

```
import requests
import time
import json
import os

class TelegramBot:
  def __init__(self):
    token = '6049366383:AAHU8r3Da0xcECcflPibLB08KalKS7f8ZFo'
    self.url_base = f'api.telegram.org/bot{token}/'
  #Inicar o Bot
  def Iniciar(self):
    update_id = None
    while True:
      atualizacao = self.obter_mensagens(update_id)
      mensagens = atualizacao['result']
      if mensagens:
        for mensagem in mensagens:
          update_id = mensagem['update_id']
          chat_id = mensagem['message']['from']['id']
          eh_primeira_mensagem = mensagem['message']['message_id'] == 1
          resposta = self.criar_resposta(mensagem, eh_primeira_mensagem)
          self.responder(resposta,chat_id)
  #Obter Mensagens
  def obter_mensagens(self,update_id):
    link_requisicao = f'{self.url_base}getUpdates?timeout=100'
    if update_id:
      link_requisicao = f'{link_requisicao}&offset={update_id + 1}'
    resultado = requests.get(link_requisicao)
    return json.loads(resultado.content)
  # Criar uma Resposta
  def criar_resposta(self,mensagem,eh_primeira_mensagem):
    return f'''Ola Bem Vindo{os.linesep}'''
  # Responder
  def responder(self,resposta,chat_id):
    # enviar
    link_de_envio = f'{self.url_base}sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={resposta}'
    requests.get(link_de_envio)

bot = TelegramBot()
bot = Iniciar()
```

i'm trying to create a bot for telegram but now i'm stuck on this error i don't know how to resolve.
The idea is to be a bot that I write a message and it repeats the same message but already formatted

Comment: `bot.Iniciar()` should do it. Iniciar is a method of the TelegramBot class, not a function.

Comment: Moreover, you reassign the result of Iniciar to the variable bot, are you sure this is what you want ?

Comment: in the future, please post the error as text in the question, not as a picture.

Comment: You left your **Private Bot Token** in your code. You should revoke it **ASAP** by talking to the [@BotFather](https://t.me/BotFather). People might abuse the token.